# How to center a width unknown button in a bootstrap's span?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button generated by backbone.js and jQuery.tmpl() and width of the button is variant. I want to put it in a span6 div. Code is shown below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <button class="btn primary large">
      BLABLABLA
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="span10">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make the button centered in the div.

Comment: I using bootstrap css framework form twitter. Their [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Im no CSS guru but this does the trick for me (centers the button within the span6):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6" style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn primary large">
      BLABLABLA
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info on centering [can be found here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Comment: Bootstrap 3: <div class="col-md-12"><div class="text-center">xxx</div></div>

Answer (score 19):

A bit late but you can use the pagination-centered class from bootstrap

```
<div class="span6 pagination-centered">
  <button class="btn primary large">
    BLABLABLA
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

## What about `<a>` tags?

If you have an `<a>` tag button, then the other approaches won't work, as `a.btn` has a `float: left` attribute in the bootstrap source.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button text</a>
</div>
```

This can be undone 2 ways.

## Solution 1

Add a custom less file and import bootstrap.

**bootstrap-custom.less**

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
a.btn {
    float: none !important;
}
```

And then compile your custom less file, or simply specify it in another CSS file:

**styles.css**

```
a.btn {
    float: none !important;
}
```

## Solution 2

Simply do it inline using `style="float: none;"`:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="btn" style="float: none;">Button text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Other Solution

```
<div class="row-fluid pagination-centered">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Button</a>
    </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I wrapped the in

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Text Here</a>
```

Became

```
<div class="text-center">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Text Here</a>
</div>
```